# how give desktop or mobile XPages when using Mobile Theme XPages

Tags: themes, xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hello this is a stupid and very simple question
[image]

If you have set into the XPages proprierties the flag "use mobile themes for Xpages with prefix" in all XPages that begin with **m_** the runtime add theme and CSS/JS resources for mobile..is it correct?

So... I have created two XPages named index.xsp and m_index.xsp

I need to redirect to correct XPages if the device is a Mobile (index.xsp) or Deskop (m_index.xsp).
The only solution that I found is create a startup XPages named for example "redirect.xsp" and in BeforePageLoad event insert the SSJS code that read a User-Agent for redirect 302.

Is the good way or you have another best solution?

Tnx to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domino 9.0.1 provides a Redirect control, e.g.:

```
<xe:redirect id="redirect1">
    <xe:this.rules>
        <xe:redirectPhoneRule url="/m_Contacts.xsp"></xe:redirectPhoneRule>
    </xe:this.rules>
</xe:redirect>
```

It also allows you to redirect based on tablet, request header or custom rules. That is the recommended method for redirecting, but will require a 9.0.1 Domino server.